# Mobile slide in menu sub panel toggle not working

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, toggle, slide

H,
I have been working on the following mobile hamburger menu and although it works on desktop view in a small reduced window it doesn't work on an actual mobile screen. After the menu slides into view, the menu items don't reveal the sub menu items on click. What could be the issue with slideToggle that doesn't work on mobile device? Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
 <li class="nav-item mainMenu">
        <a href="" class="mainMenuTitle menuClosed">Menu Title 1</a>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            <ul class="sub-nav-group">
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item mainMenu">
        <a href="" class="mainMenuTitle menuClosed">Menu Title 1</a>
        <div class="sub-nav">
            <ul class="sub-nav-group">
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.sub-nav').hide();

    $(".nav-item a").click(function(){      
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
        $(this).toggleClass('menuClosed menuOpened');
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Well for starters, your `< a>`  tag should look like this: `<a href="#"></a>`

Comment: Adding the pound sign to the <a> href doesn't solve the toggle issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul>
  <li class="dropdown-toggle">Menu item 1
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>submenu item 1</li>
        <li>submenu item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-toggle">Menu item 2
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Submenu item 1</li>
        <li>Submenu item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("li").children("ul")){
    $("li").children("ul").hide();
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).find("ul").slideToggle("normal");
    });
  }
});
```

You can edit it however you like and still get the same functionality.